# How do I use CUDA driver functions?

Tags: c++, cuda

I have a GUI application with a producer thread and an OpenGL thread, the OpenGL thread needs to call CUDA functions and the producer needs to call `cudaMemcpy` etc.

No matter what I do I can't seem to get the CUDA driver api to work. Every time I try to use these function I get a `cudaErrorMissingConfiguration`.

I want to use multi-threaded CUDA, what is the paradigmatic way to accomplish this?

**Original**

```
void program::initCuda()
{
    CUresult a;pctx=0;
    cudaSafeCall(cudaSetDevice(0));
    cudaSafeCall(cudaGLSetGLDevice(0));
    a=cuInit(0);
    cudaSafeCall(cudaFree(0));
    cout <<"cuInit :" <<a << endl;assert(a == cudaSuccess);
    //a=cuCtxGetCurrent(pctx);
    a=cuCtxCreate(pctx,CU_CTX_SCHED_AUTO,0);
    cout <<"GetContext :" <<a << endl;assert(a == cudaSuccess);
    //Fails with cudaErrorMissingConfiguration
    a=cuCtxPopCurrent(pctx);
    cout <<"cuCtxPopCurrent :" <<a << endl;assert(a == cudaSuccess);
    cout <<"Initialized CUDA" << endl;
}
```

**Revised**

```
void glStream::initCuda()
{
    CUresult a;
    pctx=0;
    cudaSafeCall(cudaSetDevice(0));
    cudaSafeCall(cudaGLSetGLDevice(0));
    cudaFree(0);// From post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415204/how-to-create-a-cuda-context seems to indicate that `cudaSetDevice` should make a context.
    a=cuCtxGetCurrent(pctx);
    cout <<"GetContext :" <<a << endl;assert(a == cudaSuccess);
    a=cuCtxPopCurrent(pctx);
    cout <<"cuCtxPopCurrent :" <<a << endl;assert(a == cudaSuccess);
    cout <<"Initialized CUDA" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Either use the driver API to create a context, or use the runtime API. But don't use *both*, which is what you have now.

Comment: @talonmies I made a revision to the post but it still doesn't help, I can't seem to help, it still reports error code `1`.

Comment: Now you don't have any context establishment at all. `cudaSetDevice` does not establish a context.

Comment: @talonmies Okay I added a `cudaFree(0)`, but that doesn't seem to work. How do I actually create a context? Also this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415204/how-to-create-a-cuda-context seems to indicate that `cudaSetDevice` should make a context.

Comment: Perhaps you could look at one of the [cuda samples](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html) that uses the driver API, like [vectorAddDrv](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#vector-addition-driver-api) to learn how to use the driver API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest version of your second code should look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

int main(void)
{
    CUresult a;
    CUcontext pctx;
    cudaSetDevice(0); // runtime API creates context here
    a = cuCtxGetCurrent(&pctx);
    std::cout << "GetContext : " << a << std::endl;
    assert(a == CUDA_SUCCESS);
    a = cuCtxPopCurrent(&pctx);
    std::cout << "cuCtxPopCurrent : " << a << std::endl;
    assert(a == CUDA_SUCCESS);
    std::cout << "Initialized CUDA" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

which yields the following on OS X 10.6 with CUDA 5.0:

```
$ g++ -I/usr/local/cuda/include -L/usr/local/cuda/lib driver.cc -lcuda -lcudart
$ ./a.out
GetContext :0
cuCtxPopCurrent :0
Initialized CUDA
```

ie. "just works". Here the context is lazily initiated by the `cudaSetDevice` call (note I incorrectly asserted that `cudaSetDevice` doesn't establish a context, but at least in CUDA 5 it appears to. This behaviour may have changed when the runtime API was revised in CUDA 4).

Alternatively, you can use the driver API to initiate the context:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

int main(void)
{
    CUresult a;
    CUcontext pctx;
    CUdevice device;
    cuInit(0);
    cuDeviceGet(&device, 0);
    std::cout << "DeviceGet : " << a << std::endl;
    cuCtxCreate(&pctx, CU_CTX_SCHED_AUTO, device ); // explicit context here
    std::cout << "CtxCreate : " << a << std::endl;
    assert(a == CUDA_SUCCESS);
    a = cuCtxPopCurrent(&pctx);
    std::cout << "cuCtxPopCurrent : " << a << std::endl;
    assert(a == CUDA_SUCCESS);
    std::cout << "Initialized CUDA" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

which also "just works":

```
$ g++ -I/usr/local/cuda/include -L/usr/local/cuda/lib driver.cc -lcuda -lcudart
$ ./a.out
DeviceGet : 0
CtxCreate : 0
cuCtxPopCurrent : 0
Initialized CUDA
```

What you shouldn't do is mix both as in your first example. All I can suggest is try both of these and confirm they work for you, then adopt the call sequences to whatever it is you are actually trying to achieve.