# hybrid graphics CUDA starting

Tags: cuda, gpu

I have a hybrid graphic laptop and I'm using Windows 7, I'm intending to run a C++ code containing also **cuda**,when it's GPU's turn to start up, my nvidia GPU takes some seconds to just start up,and again I guess it takes some other seconds to warm up, is there any way to start up GPU just after running a code(for example in first line of **main()** function)?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Mostly the warm-up issue is because the GPU needs to setup a context with CPU. More on CUDA context setup - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415204/how-to-create-a-cuda-context

Comment: This "warm-up" delay is primarily due to loading the CUDA dll's into memory.  That's why Robert suggested calling a cudaFree(0) early in your program's life - to force the loading of the large CUDA dll's at program startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting a:

```
cudaSetDevice(0);
```

as the first line of your `main` function.   Or you could also try using:

```
cudaFree(0);
```

Answer (score 3):

I propose a better option. Since you are using Windows, have you considered forcing the program to start with the NVIDIA GPU? If you are using NVIDIA Optimus (a laptop without a physical switch for switching graphic cards) try this:

Right click on the program that uses CUDA, in the context menu, there is an option named `"Run with graphics processor"` and under there choose `"High-performance NVIDIA processor"`.
Note that if you are using Visual Studio, you could start Visual Studio with this method. This way, your non-CUDA card will not be visible to the program :-)

Based on my experience if you are trying to do CUDA/OpenGL interop, without this method you will have problems. Sometimes the OpenGL context is created for your non-NVIDIA card and the CUDA context is created on the NVIDIA card, leading to bizarre errors.